# how to convert column names into column values in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=['x','y'], data={'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]})
```

how can I convert column names into values of a column? This is my desired output

```
   c1  c2
x  1   a
x  3   b
y  2   a
y  4   b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
print (df.T.unstack().reset_index(level=1, name='c1')
                     .rename(columns={'level_1':'c2'})[['c1','c2']])
   c1 c2
x   1  a
x   3  b
y   2  a
y   4  b
```

Or:

```
print (df.stack().reset_index(level=1, name='c1')
                 .rename(columns={'level_1':'c2'})[['c1','c2']])
   c1 c2
x   1  a
x   3  b
y   2  a
y   4  b
```

Comment: Glad can help you! And thank you for super sample in question.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
In [279]: df.stack().reset_index().set_index('level_0').rename(columns={'level_1':'c2',0:'c1'})
Out[279]:
        c2  c1
level_0
x        a   1
x        b   3
y        a   2
y        b   4
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index(-1).iloc[:, ::-1]
df1.columns = ['c1', 'c2']
df1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
In [62]: (pd.melt(df.reset_index(), var_name='c2', value_name='c1', id_vars='index')
          .set_index('index'))
Out[62]: 
      c2  c1
index       
x      a   1
y      a   2
x      b   3
y      b   4
```